# Situation with signed_request, sessions and PHP SDK 3.0

Tags: facebook, session, signed

I am making an application and on the "front" page of the Tab I get the signed_request. But when I navigate to different pages on the app it stops providing the data.

So far this work:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();<br />
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');<br />
echo $user_profile['id'];<br />
echo $user_profile['name'];
echo $_SESSION['signed_request']; // Returns the data
```

But when I navigate to other pages, it doesn't give anything.
It looses everything. How can I keep the data from the signed_request? Do I need to use sessions in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the signed request isn't always passed to each page, so I used the following to hold that myself in the session object.  I set this on the login page before I redirect to other pages in my app:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["SR"]))
    $_SESSION["SR"] = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

$signed_request = $_SESSION["SR"];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's all that was needed to get everything working. Now when I click on different pages I don't loose the signed_request and I can do queries to the API with the PHP SDK 3.0.